# Multiple UITableViews in a Single Class

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

In a single UiView controller class i've added 3 UITableView.

```
UITableView *ChaptersTableView;

UITableView *SubChaptersTableView;

UITableView *SubTopics1TableView;
```

Now in ViewDidLoad of class i've initialized these TableView's & calling the Delegate & Datasource methods on these Table View's.

```
ChaptersTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
ChaptersTableView.delegate=self;
ChaptersTableView.dataSource=self;

SubChaptersTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
SubChaptersTableView.delegate=self;
SubChaptersTableView.dataSource=self;



SubTopics1TableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
SubTopics1TableView.delegate=self;
SubTopics1TableView.dataSource=self;
```

I wish to have different content & height for rows of different Table views. For eg. TableView1 will have cell height of 20, TableView2 will have cell height of 40 & TableView3 will have cell height of 60.

So how do i go about customizing these delegate & datasource methods depending on the tableView they are called for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate methods return the tableview object. Hence while creating you can tag the tableviews like this. `SubTopics1TableView.tag = 0, SubChaptersTableView.tag = 1` etc.

In your delegate methods check the tag and configure the tableviews.
For eg

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(tableview.tag == 0)
// Customise this tableview
}
```

To change how the cell will look you can use the delegate method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

To change the height of the row you can use:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: The `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method can't help you to change the cell's height!

Comment: Well yes, there are other methods where it can be done. Was just giving an idea.

Comment: You should give a proper example then. Your answer is clearly misleading.

Comment: "So how do i go about customizing these delegate & datasource methods depending on the tableView they are called for?" -- Giving an idea with one delegate method should work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIden = nil;
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if(  [mTableView1 isEqual:tableView ])
    {
        cellIden = @"Cell1";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIden];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIden];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [mList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    if(  [mTableView2 isEqual:tableView ])
    {
        cellIden = @"Cell2";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIden];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIden];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [mArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

assign tag to each table ....

```
-(CGFloat )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
 if(tableView.tag==1)
     return 20;
 else if(tableView.tag==2)
     return 40;
 else if(tableView.tag==3)
     return 60;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from a test like this: `tableView==ChaptersTableView`? An instance cannot be equal to a class.

Answer (score 0):

To modify a cell's height you have to implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in the delegate class, not the data source. You can attach the same delegate to all the three tables and implement that method this way:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView kindOfClass:[ChaptersTableView class]])
        return 20;
    else if ([tableView kindOfClass:[SubChaptersTableView class]])
        return 40;
    else if ([tableView kindOfClass:[SubTopics1TableView class]])
        return 60;
    else return 44;
}
```

This solution will work if you plan to use different tables with different, but unique, classes. If you plan to differentiate the cell's height for two different tables that implement the same class (eg class of `tableView1` == class of `tableView2` == `Class1`), you should set a different flag in that class' implementation and test for that flag's value.

Let me know if this can help